# Ruby: how can I retrieve a value in a hash knowing its (array) path?

Tags: ruby, hash, traversal

I've got this hash

```
parentNode = {
  "titles" => { 
    "primary" => "On Days Like These",
    "secondary" => "Matt Monro",
    "tertiary" => nil
  },
  "synopses" => nil,
  "image_url" => "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/{recipe}/p01bqrb8.jpg",
  "duration" => nil
}
```

and I know the 'path' of the value I want :

```
path = ['titles','secondary']
```

How can I retrieve the corresponding value, which is *Matt Monro* ?

This works

```
puts parentNode['titles']['secondary']
```

but what I want is to fetch that same data using the *path* variable defined above.  But

```
  puts parentNode[path]
  puts parentNode.dig(path)
```

does not shows anything.

I'm new to ruby, why is this not working ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to read the docs, here [Hash#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig), more carefully. The argument for ’dig` is not an array.

Comment: thanks. not always easy to understand the subtilities when you come from another language.

Comment: My comment may have come across as a criticism. That was not my intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Hash.dig` accepts variable number of arguments, to convert array into "variable arguments" you need to use `*` ([splat operator](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/07/ruby-operators/#Ruby_Splat_Operator_With_Examples))

```
parentNode.dig(*path)
```